# Dynamic Module loading from external source

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, dynamic, import

I need to load a react component from an external source.

```
   myUrl = "http.//myOtherwebsite/.../myComponent.js";
   myComponent= React.lazy(() => import(/* webpackIgnore: true */ myUrl));
```

The HTTP response status is 200 ok, with the right file ( I solved any CORS issue).

I have the error:

```
        TypeError: "undefined has no properties"
```

and the component is not built.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had much luck getting webpackIgnore to actually ignore the import call. Because of this, the return value of import() is undefined instead of the actual module.  When webpack does this, the file at yourUrl isn't even fetched at all. You get 'undefined has no properties' because the returned undefined is going into the React machinery instead of the actual module.

My solution to this issue may not help, but here goes:  in my Typescript config file `tsconfig.json`, I had the option `removeComments` set to True, which is a normal thing to do.  But it was stripping out the webpackIgnore comment before webpack saw it, hence webpack didn't ignore the import() and what it replaced it with returned the undefined that's troubling you.